# How to encrypt a parameter and send it from view to controller

Tags: codeigniter, encryption, parameters

It is the first time I want to use encrypt class.I need to encrypt a value from  view and send it as a  parameter of a function in controller.In controller I do this:

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
```

in view I have this link:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/article_cont/show_public/<?php $this->encrypt->encode($row->art_id)?>">continue</a>
```

when I click on this link it goes to `show_public` function in controller but does not pass the parameter to this function.what is the problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to print it out.

Just:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/article_cont/show_public/<?php echo $this->encrypt->encode($row->art_id)?>">continue</a>
```

Changed:

```
<?php echo $this->encrypt->encode($row->art_id)?>
```

Add 'echo' to it.

I think it will work.

Comment: The parameter is shown in url now.But now it shown an error which says the URI submitted has disallowed characters.How can I correct it?

Comment: This might be caused by the encryption function. To solve it, you can use urlencode() function to encode it. See: http://sg2.php.net/urlencode